# If the command fails then terminate the application Linux(Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example:

```
if (process.getuid () === 0) {`
    console.log ('root user');
    // do something
} else {
    console.log ('No root user')
    exec ('bash -c git clone https://github.com/**', function (error, stdOut, stdErr)
}
```

How to make sure that if the `exec ('bash -c git clone https://github.com/**', function (error, stdOut, stdErr)` command does not work, then the application terminates? And if it works, it continues to continue

Answer (score 0):

Well, the callback function gives you errors if any, right? Use that to end the program :

```
exec ('bash -c git clone https://github.com/**', function (error, stdOut, stdErr){
  if(error) process.exit();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I pack yarn package I get errors "error Command failed with exit code 2"

Comment: Everything is fine, just rechecked. But there is one thing, the application still starts even when the command is executed without errors. And I need the command to start first, and then the application.